I have an error using dropzone.js in a modal
I am using Angular 10 to create a form. At a certain point a modal with a dropzone must be displayed to load images. But when trying to get the saved images I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'directiveRef')
The html code is as follows:
<ng-template #imagesModal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header p-4 lg-border-radius align-items-center">
    <h5 class="modal-title m-0"
    >Add Images</h5>

    <button class="btn-close" type="button" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"
    ><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <dropzone class="dropzone" [config]="dzoptions"></dropzone>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveImages()">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

And the ts code is this:
import { DropzoneComponent, DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
...
  @ViewChild(DropzoneComponent) componentRef: DropzoneComponent;
  dropzone: any;

  private imageFiles = [];
  public dzoptions: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Da click o arrastra para subir archivos',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    dictCancelUpload: 'Cancelar carga',
    dictRemoveFile: 'Quitar imagen',
    dictInvalidFileType: 'No puedes subir archivos de este tipo',
    resizeWidth: 1000,
    resizeHeight: 1000,
    resizeMethod: 'contain',
    resizeQuality: 1.0,
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/post'
  };

  saveImages() {
    this.dropzone = this.componentRef.directiveRef.dropzone();
    this.imageFiles = this.dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
  }

Does anyone know what configuration I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong?
In other views I have used dropzone without problems, but when I try to use it with the modal that is where I get that error.

This error that you face, is typically happens when Angular hasn't initialized the DropzoneComponent yet.
A solution is to delay the saveImages() function until the DropzoneComponent is initialized.
This is how you can modify your code:
import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DropzoneComponent, DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';

export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(DropzoneComponent, { static: false }) componentRef: DropzoneComponent;

  private imageFiles = [];
  public dzoptions: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    // your dropzone config options
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Ensure that componentRef is initialized before accessing it
    if (this.componentRef) {
      // Call saveImages after DropzoneComponent is fully initialized
      this.saveImages();
    }
  }

  saveImages() {
    // Check if componentRef and directiveRef are defined
    if (this.componentRef && this.componentRef.directiveRef) {
      // Access dropzone method using directiveRef
      this.imageFiles = this.componentRef.directiveRef.dropzone().getAcceptedFiles();
    }
  }
}

